# JQuery swal confirmation doesn't submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I'm trying to create a confirmation using `sweet alert`. When user clicks on button, the `swal` (alert) window is opened and they can either confirm or cancel. If `confirm` is clicked, then `JQuery` should click on that.

But it doesn't do anything. Do you know where is the problem?

I've tried multiple options - `unbind.click()` etc..

```
$('.button-apply').on('click', function (e) {
        var t = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Do you want to apply for this job?",
            type: "info",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#b3ff99",
            confirmButtonText: "Confirm",
            //closeOnConfirm: false,
            //showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            html: false
        }, function (isConfirm) {
            if (!isConfirm) {
                return;
            } else {
                t.click();
            }
        })

    })
```

**EDIT:**
Changed `} else {
                    t.click();
                }`

to

```
} else {
                t.unbind('click');
                t.trigger('click');
            }
```

which successfully unbind it but `t.trigger('click')` does not execute.

**SOLVED:**

Since it's a `<a href....>`, I couldn't do `t.submit()` when it's unbinded so I've replaced `t.click()` with `window.location.href = t.attr('href');` and it works correctly.

Comment: I've already tried that and it doesn't work. Maybe because preventDefault... {
                t.trigger('click');
            }

Comment: This will take you in infinitive loop of clicking the same button when user click confirm. I tested it it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have specified [`e.preventDefault();`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) which will prevent the event on `button-apply` from firing.   Remove this line and the click event will come back.

As an additional note when the user presses cancel you fire the same event again which will cause an infinite loop.   You should remove the `t.click();` and place your logic you want to invoke if the user performs this action.

As an example:

```js
$('.button-apply').on('click', function (e) {
        var t = $(this);
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Do you want to apply for this job?",
            type: "info",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#b3ff99",
            confirmButtonText: "Confirm",
            //closeOnConfirm: false,
            //showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            html: false
        }, function (isConfirm) {
            if (!isConfirm) {
                alert('You have not applied for the job!');
            } else {
                alert('You have applied for the job');
                // Submit form $("#yourForm").submit();
                // or an AJAX call.
            }
        })

    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>


<button class="button-apply">Click me</button>
```

Comment: But when I remove preventDefault, it doesn't wait for confirmation. It confirms it and user can't click on cancel.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik - I have included some code to help you, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: No it doesn't work. If I click on cancel, it alerts but acts like I clicked on confirm. On the other hand, t.unbind('click') would be a good idea if it was a form but it is a <a href....>. I've finally managed it to work - instead of t.click(), I did: window.location.href = t.attr('href');